# Can you use Shimano 11 speed chain pins on a 10 speed chain?

Tags: chain, compatibility

I want to purchase a spare pin for my Shimano Ultegra 10 speed chain.  Looking around I can only see 11 speed pins for sale.  Can I put these into a 10 speed chain?

Comment: Why would you purchase a spare pin instead of a spare quick-link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that the chain pins for Shimano 10-speed chains are 6.0mm in length and the pins for the 11-speed chains are 5.8mm in length. That is pretty close, but I wouldn't chance it. I also don't know for sure if the pin diameter is the same and I don't have an 11-speed pin to measure.

A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=shimano%2011%20speed%20chain%20pin&oq=shimano%2011%20speed%20chain%20pin&aqs=chrome..69i57.10515j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=shimano%2010%20speed%20chain%20pin&tbm=shop) turns up many places where you can purchase the 10-speed pins. Even better - I have to believe that nearly every local bike shop in your area would carry 10-speed compatible pins.

Comment: +1 for having the actual width of the pins. I knew they were different, but not by how much.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 11 speed chain is narrower, the connection pin will be narrower than for a 10 speed. While it might work, I certainly wouldn't recommend it.

What you can do is use a SRAM [powerlock](http://www.sram.com/sram/road/technologies/powerlock) designed for 10 speed applications.

Comment: 10 speed is powerLOCK, not powerLINK. Powerlock is 1 time use, powerlink is multi use (officially anyway - there is a tread on bicycles.SE on reusing powerlinks). Connex and KMC make multi-use quick links for 10 and 11 speed chains as well. Note that Shimano doesn't officially condone doing this, but some people have used other link systems other than Shimano's without adverse effects (other people complain that something is rubbing).

Comment: Yep, I changed to lock not link. Thanks @Batman